# cargar una imagen en html y javascript

Tags: javascript, html, post

Estoy enviando a mi web server una imagen que selecciono desde mi HTML de la siguiente manera:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://'+ip+'/HelloSpringMVC/uploadFile" action="subirFoto();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   File to upload: <input type="file" name="file"><br/>
   <input type="submit" value="Upload"> Press here to upload the file!
</form>
```

Mi problema es que haciendo esto ademas de hacer el `POST` con la imagen a mi web server me redirige la página a esa dirección cosa que no quiero que ocurra, quiero que se mantenga en el HTML en el que está, ¿ cómo podría solucionarlo?

También me gustaría conocer si esto puede realizarse en Javascript

Comment: Para poder ayudarte debes colocar también el código javascript

Answer (score 3):

Use [formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) para cargar archivo.

**HTML**:

```
<input type="file" id="filechooser">
```

**Javascript**:

```
function uploadFile() {
    var blobFile = $('#filechooser').files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("fileToUpload", blobFile);

    $.ajax({
       url: "upload.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: formData,
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       success: function(response) {
           // .. hacer algo...
       },
       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
           console.log(errorMessage); // Opcional
       }
    });
}
```

Vea la compatibilidad con los navegadores: http://caniuse.com/xhr2

> Fuente SO:
>
> - [Send Image to server using File input type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25204741/8933039)
>
> Otro ejemplo lo encuentra aquí:
>
> - [FileReader.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)

---

**Otro Ejemplo:**

```js
function mostrar(){
  var archivo = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(archivo );
    reader.onloadend = function () {
      document.getElementById("img").src = reader.result;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" onchange="mostrar()"/>
<br>
<img id="img"/>
```

Comment: A ese HTML le he añadido un onchange=uploadFile(); para invocar la función, pero tengo problemas con var blobFile = $('#filechooser').files[0]; ya que no es capaz de recoger el valor del filechooser

Comment: @Silvia prueve asi: `var blobFile = document.getElementById("filechooser").files[0];`

Comment: @Silvia he colocado otro código de ejemplo pruebe!

Answer (score 0):

OK primero tienes que usar un evento en ajax para guardar la imagen y no te rediccione la pagina y usar un evento file upload de jquery para subir la imagen, en mi caso yo utilizo fileupload de jquery aqui esta la informacion

aqui tienes la vista

```
 <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            File to upload: <input type="file" name="file"><br/>
            <input type="button" id="button" value="Upload"> Press here to upload the file!
        </form>

al input del submit lo cambiamos a button

y el jquery es 

$("#button").on("click",function(){
        var url = window.location.hostname === 'url';
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            done: function (e, data) {
                $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                    $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
                });
            }

        })
    });
```

de igual manera aqui te dejo el link del fileupload 
http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
var formulario = $('#subirFoto'); //Donde el el selector subirFoto debe estar dentro de la etiqueta form como id es decir <form id="subirFoto" enctype="multipart/form-data">

formulario.submit(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
$data = $formulario.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function () {
              //que quieres hacer antes de enviar la información
        }
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'subirFoto.php',//Ruta donde va a ser enviado el formulario
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (response) {

               //Response devuelve una respuesta del archivo subirFoto.php
               //Puede ser un json que es lo mas común utilizar en estos casos
        },
        error: function (response) {
               //En caso de que suceda algún error con el envío de información
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Estoy probando la manera que me comentó y no entiendo muy bien, he dejado el form así: 
        <form id="subirFoto();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            File to upload: <input type="file" name="file"><br/>
            <input type="button" id="button" value="Upload"> Press here to upload the file!
        </form>    El código Javascript debe ir en una funcion llamada subirFoto() o no haría falta, gracias

Comment: El **subirFoto** no es una función simplemente es un identificador que en  `jquery ` va a funcionar como selector es decir tu codigo html quedaría así `<form id="subirFoto" enctype="multipart/form-data">`  y tu selector de `jquery` es el siguiente:   `$('#subirFoto');`, aclaro para hacer todo eso debes importar `jquery` en tu proyecto